# List of run command parameter in windows 7 through registry

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, command-prompt

I am having a hard time to detect in which location I could find the command-parameter that I previously run using the cmd.exe. I am wondering if this can be found in the registry or using the WMI and convert this into text file so that i can use this to base and read through vbscript. Is there anyone who knows where it can be found?

I have a project that needs to detect the command that I inputted in the cmd.exe after it was executed. For example if I run a parameter "DIR", I need to run the script to read or find the last parameter that I used.

Comment: If you're referring to just commands entered interactively in a console, then `doskey.exe` should be what you need. It provides a command-line interface to the console history API, i.e. the history that's accessible via the F7 popup.

Comment: BTW, this is for any console application, not just cmd.exe. For example in the python.exe REPL you could call `subprocess.check_output('doskey /history /exename=python.exe').splitlines()` to get a list of your previous commands.